# Citrix Workspace Launching Several Desktops

Tags: citrix-receiver

When I click the icon for a single virtual desktop ("app") in the Citrix Workspace application on Windows, one or several other virtual desktops will also start.

How do I ensure only the clicked-on virtual desktop launches?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On windows the "Advanced Preferences" are accessed only through the Citrix Workspace tray icon.

This issue is caused by the settings here:

Advanced Preferences -> Shortcuts and Reconnect -> Reconnect Options

Unchecking "Enable Workspace Control Support" will work to prevent issue

If WCS is instead enabled AND "Reconnect Mode Used" is "On launch" AND "Reconnect to all active and disconnected sessions" is also checked, then the then clicking a single app will launch all "active" (on the server side) sessions.

WCS seems to exist to allow the "apps" to relaunch automatically, and what's going on is that several "apps" are starting.

If curious, registry keys seem to be here, with some interplay between machine and user keys:

- Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Citrix\Dazzle
- Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Citrix\Dazzle

Strangely the keys are named WSC, not WCS

Some documentation for the key values here:
https://support.citrix.com/article/CTX136339/applications-launched-from-within-published-desktop-disconnects

Seems like WCS makes sense if you are always launching same app or app(s).   I am not sure it works to track prior app and launch that by default.